# Refresh mysql div content using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Could somebody please point me in the right direction as regards refreshing a particular div using ajax. I know the basics of php, a little jquery, but Zero ajax. My scoreboard is built using php within a table as follows -

```
<div class="scoreBoard">
    <table>
        <?php
        include("lib/inc/connect.php");

        $sql="SELECT * FROM highScores ORDER BY Score DESC";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $i = 1;
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Name"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["Score"] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;
        }

        mysqli_close($con);
        ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

At the moment I have a little refresh image that refreshses the page onClick via JS. The idea of an ajax refresh would be much nicer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> save your php code in a file named `somename.php`   then call it with
>   ajax

in `somename.php`

```
<?php
  include("lib/inc/connect.php");

  $sql="SELECT * FROM highScores ORDER BY Score DESC";
  $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $i = 1;
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $i . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Name"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["Score"] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
  }
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

in your main file

```
<div class="scoreBoard"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval( refreshScoreBoard, 5000 );
  var inRequest = false;
  function refreshScoreBoard() {
    if ( inRequest ) {
      return false;
    }
    inRequest = true;
    var load = $.get('somename.php');
    $(".scoreBoard").html('Refreshing');
    load.error(function() {
      console.log( "Error" );
      // do something here if request failed
    });
    load.success(function( res ) {
      console.log( "Success" );
      $(".scoreBoard").html('<table>'+res+'</table>');
    });
    load.done(function() {
      console.log( "Completed" );
      inRequest = false;
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This works really well, thanks. I'm just trying to tweak it so then it doesn't disappear then reappear, it merely changes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

smth. like this in some event triggered function(can be time interval either):

```
$('.scoreBoard').load('path/to/php_fetching_data_and_building_table');
```

For more information (like sending post/get) check here:
[jQuery - load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

ps: you can also use 'ajax' jquery function