# Refreshing page with curl

Tags: php, curl, refresh, reload

I want to load cricket score card into my web page.is there any method so that curl reload the web site score card periodically after fixed time.

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17261050/refresh-mysql-div-content-using-ajax/17261184#17261184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a refresh header in php

```
header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php");
```

This will cause the site to refresh the url to whatever.php every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can reload the page using `javascript` like this:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
        location.reload();
    }, 10000);  // 10000 milliseconds = 10 seconds 
</script>
```